# OpenCV how to smoothen boundary

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, opencv, image-processing

I have an image and I want to create a smooth boundary. This is normally done in photoshop by smudge tool around the boundary of the image, but I'd like to do it via code.

What I want is this:

[image: What I want is this:]

My image background is alpha.

I have two solutions:

1. Take all the boundary pixels region and apply gaussian blur on only those regions. I don't know how I can extract only boundary pixels only.
2. Again, take all the boundary pixels and apply alpha at each pixel. Forexample I take 10px boundary around the image and then each pixel I apply 10% increased alpha, so the effect will be 10% alpha , 20%....100% and then the visible region.

Any help is appreciated. I'm trying to do it on iPhone with OpenCV

Answer (score 2):

All you need is simple blur (Gaussian or any other). And you don't need to extract only boundary pixels because smoothing of flat region is the same flat region, so you will see smoothing only on boundaries.

Comment: Yes, I want smoothing on only boundaries..!

Comment: Proper smoothing will affect ONLY boundaries. That's the advantage of kernel-based processing (in a very handy-wavy sense): it won't affect large connect fields of pixels of constant value.

So convolve with a 1D horizontal Gaussian kernel, then with a 1D vertical Gaussian kernel, and there you go. You could probably write the code as fast as you could write a reply.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called "Anti-aliasing". Generally the way to do it is either use some built-in technique, such as sub-sampling during render time (See OpenCV docs for anti-aliasing: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html). Or to render the image at a larger scale (say 4x the size), and then down-sample (scale the image down).

Answer (score 0):

Gaussian Blur will do the trick. You can learn more from here: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter.html

All of which are common methods of smoothing.